# Minimal path to form a string

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, theory

Given a matrix `N x M` of symbols `S` and a given sequence of symbols find the minimal path that traverses all of the symbols in a given order. Allowed directions are `UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT`.

Example:

```
Matrix:
   123
   265
   346
Sequence:
   1234561
Output:
   8 (start from top left corner, then D, D, R, R, U, L, U, L)
```

Please note that symbols can be repeated and thus graph algorithms are of no use here. **The actual path is not relevant**, only the number, hence dynamic programming is probably the way to go.

Formally: the given sequence of symbols must be a subsequence of the path.

I'm looking for an algorithm that finds the length of the shortest path described above.

Comment: Can you please add a question to the end of your post, because it is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: @Pontios Clarified. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for backtracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic programming state can be `(row, col, pos)`: the two coordinates on the board and the position in the sequence we build.

The function `f (row, col, pos)` is the minimum total distance traveled to achieve such state.

Obviously, when `matrix[row][col]` is not equal to `sequence[pos]`, the state is invalid.
We will encode it by `f (row, col, pos) = infinity`.

The base is `f (row, col, 1) = 0` for positions such that `matrix[row][col] = sequence[1]`.

The outer loop goes over the `pos` part of the state.
To find `f (row, col, pos)` in the case where `matrix[row][col]` is equal to `sequence[pos]`, we want to observe all states `(row', col', pos - 1)` and take the minimum of `f (row', col', pos - 1)` plus the distance from `(row', col')` to `(row, col)`.
This distance is just `|row - row'| + |col - col'|`.

The answer is the minimum value of `f (row, col, n)` where `n` is the length of the sequence.

Hopefully you can take it from here.

---

This approach would help even if the actual path was relevant.
To find the actual path, we could store the previous state along with the function value.
In other words, `f (row, col, pos)` can be a triple: actual answer, `row'` of the previous state, `col'` of the previous state.

Comment: Could you please clarify ```outer loop```? I got lost at that point because I don't really know what you are referring to.

Comment: @PalJereh I'd structure the solution as: `for pos = 2, 3, ..., n:`, `for row = 1, 2, ..., rows:`, `for col = 1, 2, ..., cols:`, `calculate f (row, col, pos)`. But a recursive solution with memoization would also be fine.

Comment: Shouldn't your reference to infinity be positive?

Comment: @Gassa I'm a little lost right now. Wouldn't recursive solution with memorization need NxMxInputLength space? And how does calculating eg f(2, 2, 3) (for example above) help finding the solution (as the result does not alter other variables/parts of the program).

Comment: @PalJereh The complexity is `rows * cols * n` memory and `rows^2 * cols^2 * n` time in both cases. As for calculating the values which won't be needed, indeed, the loops solution would visit some of such states. If that bothers you, there's recursive solution. Generally, implementing dynamic programming via recursion has a higher constant factor but visits less states. Which of these is stronger depends on the problem.

Comment: @Gassa Sorry to bother you, but there is surely something I'm missing in implementing your algorithm. https://pastebin.com/raw/LZfE2zAf

Comment: @PalJereh at least the infinity part doesn't work: we have to be able to calculate `f(i, j, pos - 1) + Math.Abs(row - i) + Math.Abs(row - j)` without overflow. Try `int.MaxValue / 2` for infinity instead.

Comment: @Gassa Still not working. Wrong answer on even trivial case such as table: ```1234``` and sequence: ```123```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168982/discussion-between-pal-jereh-and-gassa).

Answer (score 2):

Let `f(i, j)` represent the minimum distance to achieve the prefix of the sequence, `s`, up to length `i`, when using the `j`th instance in the matrix of the character `s[i]`. Then:

```
f(i, j) = min(d(c, j') + f(i - 1, j'))

for all j'

where d is the distance function
      c is the jth instance of the character s[i]
      j' is an instance of the character s[i - 1]
```

This solution has maximum complexity of `O(n * (r * c) * (r * c))` since there are `n` characters in the sequence and each has at most `r * c` instances. But could be significantly more efficient for inputs where the number of instances in the matrix for each character in the sequence is relatively small.

Comment: Here, `n * r * c` is the number of states, but the time complexity is `n * r * c * r * c` since there can be on the order of `r * c` choices for both `j` and `j'`. An example is a chessboard matrix of `B` and `W` squares, and the sequence `BWBWBWBWBW...BW`. A more extreme example is when the alphabet contains only one character.